# Choose table to add a row to in power automate

Tags: excel, power-automate, excel-tables

[image][image]I'm very new to power automate and I'm looking for a way to add rows to a specific table on a spreadsheet based on forms submission. For example, if the form comes from a specific city, I want to update that city's specific sheet and table in the excel file. I have about 25 sheets with 1 table in each sheet in the excel file and would like to be able to have a way update each table based on the city.
I've created a condition that allows me to add a row to a specific city's sheet in my excel file but I don't want to have to do this for all 25 city's in my file. Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?
Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Have you attempted anything by chance?

Comment: Yes, I've added a condition that allows me to update a table in a sheet for a specific city but I'd have to create this condition for all 25 cities and I don't want to do that. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: You need to show us what you've done, makes it easier to assist with an answer.  Feel free to edit your question and add more detail with screenshots, etc.

Comment: Just added a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need to do is use the dynamic nature of the `Add a row into a table` operation/action.

***Note:** This assumes that your columns are the same across each worksheet.*

As you know, when you select the table directly, you're presented with a list of columns ...

[image: Normal]

... but if you want it to work dynamically, you'll need to first specify a table name dynamically and then fill the columns using JSON, like thus ...

[image: Dynamic]

You can see, I have a parameter called `City Name` and when the user types in **Melbourne** or **Sydney**, it will use the appropriate table name in order to populate said table.

So if you haven't already worked it out, there is a table for each city and the name of each table *is* the city name.

You can then see I have to specify the JSON manually (as such) as it needs to line up with the names of the columns.

[image: Spreadsheet]

It will all then work for you.

Comment: Really appreciate this! You've made my life much easier. Thank you!!!!!